# Django admin form - ManyToMany behavior with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

When I define a ManyToMany relationship between two models like this :

```
class A (models.Model):
    pass

class B (models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Django generates two admin sections, one for each model. In the B form, I can directly create an A object, thanks to the ManyToMany relationship (and thanks to a field within the A form popping a B form).

Can this behavior be reproduced in case I use a ForeignKey ? Here is my use case :

```
class A (models.Model):
    pass

class B (models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C (models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Therefore, the user could create directly from the A form the related B objects and from these forms, C objects without nested forms (using the "popping" forms instead).

TL;DR: Basically bypassing the lack of django nested forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is feasible **but only through pop-ups** (with the already django build in admin), if you want to edit the remote object (C) from A directly in the form then you need to make changes in your admin, such as creating a special view, assigning the appropriate queries etc.
Also note that you will need to register all 3 models with the admin, otherwise you will be able to access (popup) only the models registered.